# KendoUI DropDownList to populate textboxes with data results using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

Thanks in advance...

I'm new to KendoUI controls and was trying to resolve an issue I'm having with updating textbox fields upon changing an item in the Kendo DropDownList control.

I'm populating the DropDownList using a ViewData method when the View is loaded and then calling a Json result method that returns that specific row to then use to populate the textbox fields.

I'm able to hit the Json event, but for some reason I get an error in my jquery.min.js (jQuery v1.9.1) file and the function(data) never fires off and it just skips it altogether.

Here's the error I get from the jquery.min.js file...

```
GET http://localhost:52078/Settings/GetEtilizeLocale/7 500 (Internal Server Error)       jquery.min.js:19
b.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:19
b.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:19
b.each.b.(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:19
ddlChange ViewLocales:192
i.extend.trigger kendo.all.min.js:9
o.extend._change kendo.all.min.js:14
o.extend._blur kendo.all.min.js:14
o.extend._focus kendo.all.min.js:14
o.extend._accept kendo.all.min.js:15
o.extend._click kendo.all.min.js:14
b.extend.proxy.b.isFunction.i jquery.min.js:4
b.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:4
b.event.add.v.handle
```

Here's my code...

**JS View**

```
    //Auto populate other edit popup fields when ddl changes value

    function ddlChange(e) {            
        $.get("/Settings/GetEtilizeLocale/" + $("#EtilizeLocaleID").data().kendoDropDownList.value(), function (data)
        {
            alert($('#Name').value());
            //$('#Name').val(data.name);
            //$('#LanguageCode').val(data.languagecode);
            //$('#CountryCode').val(data.countrycode);
            //$('#IsActive').val(data.isactive);
        });            
    }
```

**C# Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetEtilizeLocale(int id = 0)
    {
        var dataContext = new EtilizeEntities();
        Etilize_Locale loc = dataContext.Etilize_Locale.Find(id);

        return Json(loc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

Had to change

```
return Json(loc)
```

to

```
return Json(loc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

For anyone else who ever runs into this issue.